# infinite series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I make some exercises of analysis and I have one problem with understanding, why my argument doesn't work. So I proved this:

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then is $\sum a_n^2$ convergent.

$\textbf{Proof}$ : Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then lim($a_n$)=$0$. So $a_n$ is bounded and $\exists \ M \in \mathbb R$ with $0<a_n \leq M$. And we have from here $0<a_n^2 \leq M \cdot a_n$. Now we apply the Comparison Test and we have that $\sum a_n^2$ is convergent. QED.

But the same proof/argument doesn't work for the statement:

If $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then $\sum \sqrt{a_n}$ is also convergent. As counterexample we have $\sum 1/n^2$ is convergent, but $\sum 1/n$ is not convergent. I don't understand, why my proof will not work here? Because if I prove it by the same way, it looks like right.

$\textbf{Wrong proof}$: Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent, then lim($a_n$)=$0$. So $a_n$ is bounded and $\exists \ M \in \mathbb R$ with $0<a_n \leq M$. And we have from here $0<\sqrt{a_n} \leq \sqrt{M} $. Now we have that our sequence bounded and monoton, therefore my series has to be convergent.

I would be very grateful for help!

$\textbf{Edit}$: I understood my mistake. The partial sum has to be monoton and bounded, not sequence. It was the key.

Comment: How does $0<\sqrt{a_n} \leq M \cdot \sqrt{a_n}$ tell you anything? – You would need $0<\sqrt{a_n} \leq M \cdot a_n$ in order to apply the comparison test. But such an estimate does not hold.

Comment: @MartinR perfect. I can't say something about $M \cdot \sqrt{a_n}$ because $a_n$ is convergent, but not $\sqrt{a_n}$ . Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that all the $a_n$ are positive, since you claim that $0 < a_n \leq M$ in your first proof. Of course if this is not the case then the fact that the sequence of $a_n$ is bounded only tells us that $0 \leq |a_n| \leq M$.

For your second "proof", the issue is that $0 < a_n \leq M$ does not imply  $\sqrt{a_n} \leq M \sqrt{a_n}$. Suppose, for example, that $M = \frac{1}{2}$ (or anything less than $1$). Then $M \sqrt{a_n} < \sqrt{a_n}$, regardless of the value of $a_n$.

**P.S.** In the first proof you get $0 < a_n \leq M a_n$ because you can multiply both sides by $a_n$, which is positive and therefore preserves the inequality. I don't know how you got from $0 < a_n \leq M$ to $0 < \sqrt{a_n} \leq M \sqrt{a_n}$, but as the example above shows, it is not correct.

Comment: thank you so much. I understood my mistake!)

Comment: What Martin R said in the comments is also an issue. The fact that the inequality might not even hold stands out to me as the first problem though.

Comment: I made mistake in my inequality. It has to be if we have $0<a_n \leq M$ then $0<\sqrt{a_n} \leq \sqrt{M}$. So my sequence is bounded and monotone and therefore my series has to be convergent. It was my problem.

Comment: In that case the issue with the second proof is that just because a sequence is bounded and monotone does not mean that the series summing those terms is convergent. You gave the example yourself of $a_n = 1/n$, which is bounded above by $1$ and below by $0$, but the series $\sum 1/n$ is not convergent..

Comment: yes. I edited my question with the answer. I understood, what was wrong! But thank you!